# How to Make a Column as Hyperlink in Datagrid of telerik controls

Tags: wpf, datagrid, telerik, telerik-grid

How to make a Hyperlink column in datagrid?

Whenever the columns are binded to grid, the columns data in the grid should contain a Hyperlink.

When I click on a Hyperlink, I should get a popup?

Comment: Sry in the above question a small typo error i.e so when ever the columns are binded to grid, then the columns data in the grid should contain a Hyperlink and when i click on a Hyperlink i should get a popup.? so How to proceed

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to display a new WPF Window instead of a Web Hyperlink, is that correct?

Comment: yes i want to display a new WPF Window.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

in the sample stubbing out MyListOfItems as a List 
where one of the properties of SomeItemClass is "ItemName" to which binding a sample
column that's templated as a hyperlink..

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfItems}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="UseThisMethodToLaunchPopup">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post just for you: http://blogs.telerik.com/michaelcrump/posts/13-02-12/showing-a-hyperlink-style-button-to-popup-a-new-window-in-radgridview-for-wpf